# Snowflake: How can I find object dependency?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake: How can I find object dependency?

Development and application team is doing many changes. We need to find out object dependency before implementing new changes. This will help to avoid any negative impact from new changes.

What are views or procedures are dependent on a table?
or
What are tables/views are getting used by view or procedure?

Thank you,
Shrini

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake has some basic abilities in this regard and you should be seeing more functionality in this area coming.  Procedures and Functions are difficult considering they can be written in Javascript, but there are some references tracked that can be obtained using the `GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES` function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html